# DAC module output voltage and Arduino's digital input deviation issues

Tags: dac

I have bought a DAC module [EBF-AD5689](https://doc.embedfire.com/module/module_tutorial/zh/latest/Module_Manual/spi_class/dac.html) (in Chinese). The datasheet of AD5689 is [here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5689_5687.pdf). The pin details can be referred on page9 of the datasheet.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
#include <SPI.h>

#define SYNC 10 

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(SYNC, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SYNC, HIGH);
}

static word data = 0;

//convert the data from voltage to scale of 0-32768
word convertToScale(float voltage) {
  word scale = (word)((voltage * 32768) / 10.0);
  return scale;
}

void loop() {
  //ask for user to change the output voltage
  if (Serial.available()) { 
    float voltage = Serial.parseFloat();
    if (Serial.read() != -1) {
      data = convertToScale(voltage);
    }
  }

// refer to datasheet page 18
  byte command = 0b0010; // Update DAC Register n with contents of Input Register n
  byte address = 0b1001; // selected DAC A and DAC B
  byte dataHigh = data >> 8;
  byte dataLow = data & 0xFF; 

  digitalWrite(SYNC, LOW); 
  delay(100);

  SPI.transfer(command);
  SPI.transfer(address);
  SPI.transfer(dataHigh);
  SPI.transfer(dataLow);
  digitalWrite(SYNC, HIGH);
  delay(100);

  delay(1000);
}
```

Here is the connection:
(Arduino Uno, DAC module) --> (pin10, SYNC), (pin11, SDIN), (pin12, SDO), (pin13, SCLK).
They are just basically SPI communication between Arduino and the module.

My issues is related to the "step output voltage". I tried to use Arduino to control the module. However, there is some deviation between my digital input and measured output voltage.

[image: Relationship between input and output]

For example, if I type 1.55V in Arduino, it will keeps at the lower boundary of 1.548V. Even I type 1.599V, it also keeps at 1.548V. Until I type 1.6V, the output will change to 1.648V. In others word, no matter what I type, the output voltage are always listed on the above photo.

However, the AD5689 is a 16bit DAC and it should be more accurate. Why my offset is that large? I would like to have at least 3 d.p. accurate.

I have thought about the line `word scale = (word)((voltage * 32768) / 10.0);` in my code, which map my input voltage to the data bit. Is it possible to get voltage like 3.55V, which lies between my current "step output voltage"?

[image: schematic]

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

- Scale factor: What are you using for Vref? Have you measured its value?
- "Step" effect: I'm wondering about how `Serial.parseFloat()` actually works. How long will it wait for you to type a number? The documentation mentions a timeout, and it sounds like it's quitting after two digits. Have you tried printing the actual value of `data` to the terminal?

Comment: The Vref is 2.5V, verified by measuring the actual value on PCB.

The program keeps sending the updated value. I tried sending bits data directly, "step" effect still occur. For the actual value of the data, if I type 5(V) for example, I will get 1000000 (64 in decimal) for high bit, and 00000000 for low bit.

The power supply is stable. I think one likely reason is related to the the data I sent. I have measured the IC pin VoutA directly, which also give large "step". I wonder if the amplifier amplify the "step error" to the final A_OUT.
Schematics also updated in the question above.